# scipy.sparse dot extremely slow in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

The following code will not even finish on my system:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
p = 100
n = 50
X = np.random.randn(p,n)
L = sparse.eye(p,p, format='csc')
X.T.dot(L).dot(X)
```

Is there any explanation why this matrix multiplication is hanging?

Comment: what is `sparse`? Using `np.eye(p,p)` in place of this line, the following line is practically instantaneous.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the explicit import from scipy: from scipy import sparse.  I'm using the small matrix size as a proof of concept, in reality p is on the order of 10,000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`X.T.dot(L)` is not, as you may think, a 50x100 matrix, but an array of 50x100 sparse matrices of 100x100

```
>>> X.T.dot(L).shape
(50, 100)
>>> X.T.dot(L)[0,0]
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

It seems that the problem is that `X`'s `dot` method, it being an array, doesn't know about sparse matrices. So you must either convert the sparse matrix to dense using its `todense` or `toarray` method. The former returns a `matrix` object, the latter an `array`:

```
>>> X.T.dot(L.todense()).dot(X)
matrix([[  81.85399873,    3.75640482,    1.62443625, ...,    6.47522251,
            3.42719396,    2.78630873],
        [   3.75640482,  109.45428475,   -2.62737229, ...,   -0.31310651,
            2.87871548,    8.27537382],
        [   1.62443625,   -2.62737229,  101.58919604, ...,    3.95235372,
            1.080478  ,   -0.16478654],
        ..., 
        [   6.47522251,   -0.31310651,    3.95235372, ...,   95.72988689,
          -18.99209596,   17.31774553],
        [   3.42719396,    2.87871548,    1.080478  , ...,  -18.99209596,
          108.90045569,  -16.20312682],
        [   2.78630873,    8.27537382,   -0.16478654, ...,   17.31774553,
          -16.20312682,  105.37102461]])
```

Alternatively, sparse matrices have a `dot` method that knows about arrays:

```
>>> X.T.dot(L.dot(X))
array([[  81.85399873,    3.75640482,    1.62443625, ...,    6.47522251,
           3.42719396,    2.78630873],
       [   3.75640482,  109.45428475,   -2.62737229, ...,   -0.31310651,
           2.87871548,    8.27537382],
       [   1.62443625,   -2.62737229,  101.58919604, ...,    3.95235372,
           1.080478  ,   -0.16478654],
       ..., 
       [   6.47522251,   -0.31310651,    3.95235372, ...,   95.72988689,
         -18.99209596,   17.31774553],
       [   3.42719396,    2.87871548,    1.080478  , ...,  -18.99209596,
         108.90045569,  -16.20312682],
       [   2.78630873,    8.27537382,   -0.16478654, ...,   17.31774553,
         -16.20312682,  105.37102461]])
```

Comment: The second option `X.T.dot(L.dot(X))` is about twice as fast when you go up to p=1000 and n=500! Good catch with the array creation @Jaime.  I was thinking that the sparse matrix just wasn't a good match to the non-sparse matrix multiplication (because it turns it non-sparse, but it completely botches the operation).

Comment: Great catch, its unfortunate that numpy doesn't know about sparse matrices and doesn't provide any warnings for this unexpected behavior.